# Tree data with backend service

Tags: angular-slickgrid

I know the tree data does not support the backend service. However I would like to hack the behavior somehow as I can load the data at once (without paging) and the server can send me the data correctly sorted each time I change something.

I've patched the throws which ban the usage of treeData with multiselect, backend service etc.

When I ask for hierarchicalDataset, its correctly grouped by child/parent relations - so the setup should be correct.

However, the dataset is not displayed hierarchically, but flat and I even lose the checkbox column in the process. Do you have any suggestions on where to patch the behavior I need?

[Flat hierarchical data (Group by col is the parent ID)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orgSS.png)

I've patched the throw checks to enable grid creation, secured the treeDataOptions is correctly setup.

Comment: Update: I've managed to display the hierarchy, it just does nothing when I toggle it
[see here](https://imgur.com/a/ZVl7xke)

Comment: Update v2: Fixed columns disappearing issue (smt executed twice in my code) hierarchy still rendered with all items, although the toggle events fire and set properties correctly [see here](https://imgur.com/a/x3ARvBl)

Comment: Update v3: Finally I found where the collapsed children FILTERING happens ... in the filter when its set to filter locally... so now I just need to hack around this [works](https://imgur.com/a/GLXUiVQ)

Answer (score 0):

To enable tree collapsing/expanding with backendServiceApi, enable local filtering on the grid.

`backendServiceApi.useLocalFiltering = true`